# g++ flag to only check syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, c++98

Is there a way to have g++ check for C++98 syntax when compiling but at the same time compile as if no `-std=` has been given ? My goal is to make sure that my source code stays C++98 but I don't want to prevent g++ from using any newer optimisation or trick. For the moment, I compile my projet twice, once with `CXXFLAGS=-std=c++98` and one with a final empty `CXXFLAGS` for release.

It looks like [gcc 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html) will have `-Wc90-c99-compat` and `-Wc99-c11-compat`, that something in that direction.

Comment: I don't think such a switch could work as well for C++ as it could for C. The differences between C++03 and C++11 are not just limited to syntax, there are also major differences in which standard library headers, classes and functions are made available. True, that is also a bit of a problem with C, but not nearly as big.

Comment: What do you mean by "newer optimization or trick"?  The standard doesn't prevent any optimizations within the stated constraint that you want your source to be well-formed C++98

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *will* have to run the compiler twice, but you can save compiletime
on the `-std=c++98` pass and avoid generating unwanted object files by specifying syntax-checking only. You do that by
passing the option `-fsyntax-only`.

You'd also need to modify your `make` to skip linkage for C++98, as there'll be nothing to link.

Probably the most efficient way you could do this is with a `make` on the
following lines:

```
.phony: all clean

SRCS = foo.cpp
FLAT_SRCS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.ii,$(SRCS))
OBJS = $(patsubst %.ii,%.o,$(FLAT_SRCS))

%.ii: %.cpp
    g++ -std=c++98 $(CPPFLAGS) -E $< > $@ && g++ -std=c++98 -fsyntax-only $@

%.o: %.cpp
%.o: %.ii
    g++ -c -o $@ $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $<


all: foo

foo: $(OBJS) 
    g++ -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(FLAT_SRCS) foo
```

Here, the `%.ii: %.cpp` rule will first just preprocess the `.cpp` to the `.ii`,
then pass the already preprocessed source to a C++98 syntax-checking pass,
which produces no new file.

The empty `%.o: %.cpp` rule overrides the implicit rule that would otherwise
cause the `.cpp` to be compiled to `.o`, and it is replaced with the `%.o: %.ii`
rule to compile the `.ii`. g++ recognises `.ii` as denoting already-preprocessed
C++ source code, so it will not preprocess the source a second time.

Code is only preprocessed once, and object code is only generated once.

The linkage is as usual. Provided the C++98 syntax check passes, a `make` will look like:

```
$ make
g++ -std=c++98  -E foo.cpp > foo.ii && g++ -std=c++98 -fsyntax-only foo.ii
g++ -c -o foo.o   foo.ii
g++ -o foo   foo.o 
rm foo.ii
```

You'll note that `make` automatically deletes the preprocessed `.ii`, which is fine:
it's just a conduit between the `.cpp` and the `.o`.

All that being said, I side with @Matt McNabb's observation that you have nothing to
gain by this! Given your code *is* C++98, the compiler won't optimize it any better 
when instructed that it *must* be C++98 than when not. By time GCC gets to the
optimization stage of its business, it no longer cares what kind of source code
it started off with.

You may be supposing that `-std=c++98`, when given say to g++ 4.x, causes the
whole compiler to behave as if was g++ 2.x. Not so. It's still g++ 4.x, with the
g++ 4.x optimization tech, etc., just operating by the language definition of C++98.

There would certainly be a point in this if your code for some reason had to pass,
as C++98, on some *older* compiler than your release compiler, and in that case you
would need to distinguish the compilers in the makefile. But apparently this is not the
case. You might as well just compile conventionally with `-std=C++98`

Comment: Thank you, that's a clever thing to do. I don't want to require a newer compiler, that's why I wan't to stick a universal language set. But enforcing -std=XXX forbids g++ to do some optimizations and so on. I will do that: do a syntax-only with 98 and then really compile with no -std=.