# How can I suppress assembly files output by compilation proper?

Tags: gcc, mingw

I have some C++ library code that I want strictly compiled for a quick check, and I don't want any files produced to be used for later stages (assembly, linkage, etc.)

I can do

```
g++ -S main.cpp
```

but this will give me an assembly file that I'm just going to wind up deleting anyway.

Is there an option that will tell the compiler to just compile a source file but don't produce any files?

EDIT[0]: I'm using mingw on Windows.

Comment: `-o /dev/null` is one way.

Comment: @rici Sorry, I failed to mention I'm using mingw on Windows.

Comment: Try [-fsyntax-only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28399039/1983398).

Comment: @ssbssa That did it, mate; you should put it up as the answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc has the option [-fsyntax-only](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-fsyntax-only):

> Check the code for syntax errors, but don’t do anything beyond that.